# GraphQL quoted parameter sent with Javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, graphql

I'm trying to query a Graphql endpoint with Javascript, and am using this javascript method to create my query:

```
module.exports = (uid) =>
`{
    rich_text_data_for_uid(uid:"${uid}")
        {
            record_uid
            field_name
            row_number
            value
        }
}`.replace(/\n/g, " ");
```

This is the valid query in the explorer:

```
{
    rich_text_data_for_uid(uid:"31D2A75A3254D5EA852581D7006C2BA5")
        {
            record_uid
            field_name
            row_number
            value
        }
}
```

**Note that the JSON below is formatted to make it readable, but it does not have newlines when it's sent to the server (via the replace method call above)**

This is what gets sent as the body of my `fetch` request, and is causing problems (I suspect because of quotes):

```
{ "query": "{
    rich_text_data_for_uid(uid:"31D2A75A3254D5EA852581D7006C2BA5")
        {
            record_uid
            field_name
            row_number
            value
        }
}"
```

I have also tried escaping the quotes, and sent this as the payload:

```
{ "query": "{
    rich_text_data_for_uid(uid:\"31D2A75A3254D5EA852581D7006C2BA5\")
        {
            record_uid
            field_name
            row_number
            value
        }
}"
```

My Graphql response is always 400:

> POST body sent invalid JSON.

**Edit** When I try with variables, I get an error too:

```
    {"query":
"{ rich_text_data_for_uid(uid:$uid) {record_uid field_name row_number value } }",
"variables":{"uid":"31D2A75A3254D5EA852581D7006C2BA5"}}
```

The above says

> > Variable "$uid" is not defined.

What do I send to pass a String argument to Graphql?

Comment: do you call `fetch()` explicitly? add code how you send request

Comment: Newlines shouldn't affect the query, you can leave them in the query string if you want.

Comment: @skyboyer It's not an issue with `fetch`, I have a dozen other queries that work the same way and they are fine.

Comment: @HRK44 - Newlines should not, as you say.  However, they do, if I remove the `.replace(/\n/g, " ")` my queries do not work.  So, for whatever reason, they matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting the question - I'll post the answer I worked out:

This is the way to make it valid - we have to wrap the query string in a parameterized block that describes the variables we are passing:

```
module.exports = (uid) =>
`query rd($uid: String) {
    rich_text_data_for_uid(uid:\$uid)
        {
            record_uid
            field_name
            row_number
            pardef
            value
        }
}`.replace(/\n/g, " ");
```

That, combined with this JSON data, works fine:

```
const query = JSON.stringify({"query": richTextQueryForUid(uid), "variables": {"uid": uid}})
```